# Getting error when flushing Swatch Images Cache

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to flush swatch images cache but it shows error message:

> An error occurred while clearing the configurable swatches image
>   cache.

This exception is showing on `exception.log` file:

> Exception message: Warning:
>   include(Mage/Configurableswatches/Helper/Productimg.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: I think the problem in the word 'Configurableswatches'. If you are using linux system all of your dir. paths should be in the right case, as linux system is a case sensitive by default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems somehow your system does not hold a core file. Replacing that file will eventually erase your issue.

The file location is `app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php` and [this is the file you are](https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php) missing. Place this file there.

Comment: file is already there .